# OpenCV - Retrieve Depth and RGB from single source

Tags: c++, opencv

Ive got a Creative Senz3d camera, which supplies both depth and RGB feeds. I can access one or the other, but when attempting to access both via two seperate VideoCapture objects (i.e VideoCapture cap1(CV_CAP_INTELPERC); VideoCapture cap2(CV_CAP_IMAGE)), the program freezes during the capturing phase. Is there any way possible to access both stream via one VideoCapture object?

Comment: Guess this question is a next candidate for the tumbleweed award.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have access to that particular camera. However the opencv docs regarding the kinect suggests to do a grab() then successive retrieve() on each type of image :

```
VideoCapture capture(0); // or CV_CAP_OPENNI
for(;;)
{
    Mat depthMap;
    Mat rgbImage

    capture.grab();

    capture.retrieve( depthMap, CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP );
    capture.retrieve( bgrImage, CV_CAP_OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE );

    if( waitKey( 30 ) >= 0 )
        break;
}
```

taken from http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html